# Using Solver in VBA excel to find the optimal and specific value of "alpha" in a lot of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a forecasting workbook in excel and I'm having some trouble getting the optimal alpha value for my single exponential smoothing calculation. The sheet im working in looks as follows.
[image: The workbook I'm working in]

The calculation for all these values happen in a different sheet, I won't post these because I think they are not relevant. I played around with Solver the excel add-in to find the optimal alpha value of the first product (primer). The solver settings I used look like this:
[image: The Solver add-in settings]

When I click solve the value in cell AM2 changes to the optimal value, which is great. But I can't figure out how to do this for the other products aswell. So the destination cell will be AO3 by changing the value of AM3 and using the constraints AM3 <= 1 and AM3 >= 0. In the final version of the sheet there will be more than 700 products. I tried a search on Google but couldn't find what I was looking for.

I was thinking of creating a macro to do this but I have very limited knowledge of VBA.

Comment: Try [recording a macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-macro-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b), this will expose the VBA elements behind the solver calculation, for which you can then format into a loop to repeat for your 700 products.

Comment: @OliverCarr Thank you very much for the hint. After some more googling It now works as intended!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the hint provided by @Oliver Carr I fixed it. Hope its usefull for someone in the futher.

```
  Sub solverMacro()
'
' solverMarco Macro
'

Dim sheetName As String
Dim endRow As Integer
Dim row As Integer


sheetName = "SAP"

With Sheets(sheetName)

    endRow = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row 'gets the last used row

    For row = 2 To endRow - 1 Step 1 'This loops through all rows that are being used
        SolverReset 'resets the solver

        SolverOk SetCell:="$AO$" & row, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$AM$" & row, Engine _
        :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear" 'Sets the target set AO + the value of row. I did this so it will increment

        SolverAdd CellRef:="$AM$" & row, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1" 'adds the constraint. Cel AM + row smaller or equal to 1
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$AM$" & row, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0" 'adds the constraint. Cel AM + row greater or equal to 0

        SolverSolve True 'This runs the solver. True is there to make sure the dialog window does not show up

    Next row 'Goes to the next row to start all over

    MsgBox "Value is optimised" 'A msgBox to show that the macro is completed

End With

End Sub
```

Hope this helps, goodluck!